# Unique construct for passing a hash

Tags: ruby

I have never seen this construct for building a hash. `do_stuff(records: records)` Does this only work in a parameter list being sent to a method? Is it documented anywhere? I know it is Ruby 1.9+.

```
records = { 
  'example.com' => '1.2.3.4',
  'hello.com' => '44.33.22.22',
}

def do_stuff(data = {} )
 puts data
end

do_stuff(records: records)
```

Comment: Beware that the JSON hash syntax has some quirks; for example, `{:$a => 'b'}` and `{:'a-b' => 'c'}` are valid but `{$a: 'b'}` and `{'a-b': 'c'}` are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two things going on here. The  `{ key: value }` syntax is new in Ruby 1.9. It is equivalent to `{ :key => value }`.

Also, Ruby methods have some syntactical sugar that allows you to pass in a hash literal as the last argument of the method without including the curly braces. This is *not* new in Ruby 1.9. So

```
do_stuff(key: value)
```

Is equivalent to

```
do_stuff({ key: value })
```

Just to remind you, this only works if the hash is the last argument to the method.

Answer (score 0):

The new syntax for Hashes in Ruby 1.9 allows you to drop the hash rocket.

```
#Pre 1.9
{:key => value}

#1.9+
{key: value}
```

Both of the above are equivalent.

One thing to keep in mind when using the new hash syntax is that the key will always be treated as a symbol.